# How to implement Angular and ASP.NET Core OpenID autentication and authorization?

Tags: asp.net, angular, authentication, cookies, openid

I use OKTA to OpenID authentication and auth. Currently I use razor pages in my app but I want to make it Web API with Angular.

This is my current flow :

```
click LogIn button 
    > trigger action login 
    > go to okta and log with credentials 
    > okta sends me cookies and they are saved in browser
```

Code:

```
public IActionResult Login()
{
        if (!HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return Challenge(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

        // how to change this method to return to angular instead of using Razor pages
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

What I can do later? My cookies looks like that after I will successfully log into okta:

[image]

Now I want to know what I can do , how to change this method to return something to Angular?

It should send this cookies or something like that? Or change this cookies to jwt ?